# Why is the Gray code called a cyclic code?

Tags: binary, code

I understand why it is called reflexive and a unit distance code. I don't see any cyclic pattern which is repeating in the code. Why is it called a cyclic code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**cyclic**
ˈsʌɪklɪk,ˈsɪklɪk/
*adjective*
1. occurring in cycles; regularly repeated.

You haven't given a reference for the 'cyclic code' terminology but there is certainly a cyclic patter. This is most obvious in an encoder disc.

[image]

*Figure 1. The cyclic pattern of each bit is clearly visible on this optical absolute encoder disc.*

Each bit has a repeating on-off pattern with a 50% mark-space ratio. The bits are arranged so that only one bit changes at a time. This prevents errors on transitions from one code to the adjacent one due to misalignment of sensors, etc.

There's a generic definition about the cyclic nature of the Gray code further down the Wikipedia [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code) article mentioned in altai's answer: "The last entry in Gn differs by only one bit from the first entry. (The code is cyclic.)". That is it can wrap while still maintaining only one-bit change.

It would be possible to generate a Gray-ish code that didn't have this property if, for example, the number of steps was not even or a power of 2. This might be acceptable in a linear encoder which wouldn't need to wrap.

Comment: +1 for nice disk.. Not sure about the clearly part though... my eyes are doing weird things looking at that ;D

Comment: Even in normal binary code, each bit has an on-off pattern of 50%. Why is it not cyclic ?

Comment: The binary code is cyclic too but not suitable for encoder applications. I presume you understand why we use the Gray code in the first place. If not, let me know and I can expand my answer later.

Comment: @Transistor What about excess-3 code ? Why is not cyclic ? Except for the first number, even in excess 3 code every bit has on-off ratio of 50%

Comment: @Zephyr: I'm not sure why you're asking. Excess-3 is not a Gray code which is the topic in discussion here.

Comment: @Transistor Yes I know it's bit off topic. But your definition of on-off ratio confused me a bit. So I asked it here.

Comment: @Zephyr: Fair enough. I'm not a subject matter expert so I started with the dictionary definition of cyclic and the encoder disc shows a cyclic pattern for each bit. Then I looked at the Gray code article (not) referenced by altai and reckoned that the *cyclic* term refers to the roll-over and that the one-bit-change-per-step still applies at that point. I suspect that that feature means that for a binary encoder it must have \$ 2^n \$ steps where *n* is an integer. I am not in a position to provide a proof for that.

Comment: @Transistor: Excess-3 __is__ a Gray code.  It's used when you want to transmit a 1-of-10 choice (a decimal digit, perhaps): the regular Gray code does not have the desired "only one bit changes" property when wrapping between 9 and 0, so we use 3..12 instead.

Comment: @jasonharper: A straight binary excess-3 code would have hex values 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C in sequence, with all four bits changing between 7-8 and C-3.  On the other hand, if one xors each bit with the preceding one, then the sequence would be 2 6 7 5 4 C D F E A, with bit changes 4 1 2 1 8 1 2 1 4 8 (making it a cyclic Gray code).

Comment: That's a pretty awesome looking encoder disk... Any idea what the resolution of that would be?

Comment: @MattClark: Can you not work it out from the answer? How many bits does it have? How many steps does that give you?

Answer (score 15):

Take the four bit Gray code sequence below and print it out then cut it out with scissors. Then wrap the ends round and tape them together so you have a Gray-code band.

[image]

As you rotate the band notice there is only one bit change between every spot that is facing you, even when you cross the tape.

That is, it is a cyclic code that has no start and no end.

This is why Gray Code, named after it's inventor [Frank Gray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Gray_(researcher)), is used for encoders where single bit transitions removes the uncertainty of having two bits changing at the same time.

[image]

Comment: The diagram at the end explains everything. +1.

Answer (score 9):

> The Gray code for decimal 15 rolls over to decimal 0 with only one switch change. This is called the "cyclic" property of a Gray code.

Straight from the Wikipedia article.